# I am Getting Launch Error when I am trying to run java program in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, runtime-error

Problem : While I am trying to run java application on Eclipse I get Launch Error.

Warning : Build path specifies, execution environment JavaSE 1.8 There are no JRES installed in the workspace that are strictly compatiable with this environment.

Which is Giving "Launch Error"

I tried to set the system variables and path etc in envi variables. tried all ways but it still showing the Launch error

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions of Java available. The "Execution Environment" (a section in the Eclipse Preferences under "Java" and "Installed JREs") specifies what version of Java is required. Your application is using an execution environment that specifies Java 8, or "jdk 1.8".

Besides installing Eclipse, you have to have an appropriate version of Java installed.  Typically, Eclipse comes with its own Java installation.  We can't tell what version of Eclipse you have.  It's possible you have a very old version installed, which was released before Java 8 was released.

You can go to the following web site to get Java distributions for installation: https://jdk.java.net/8/

Once you install it, you can register that "Installed JRE" in the Eclipse preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The Eclipse I am Using is : Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212.  So As you said i installed jdk-19 and set the path. And put the compiler compilance level to 9 (in the project properties). Still Launch Error.

Comment: The Execution Environment set in the project has to have an associated JRE set in preferences. If you don't have that, you will get that error.

Comment: Great, I resolved Issue. I appericate your time.